# Destructuring parameters (TypeError: null has no properties)

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I've a function with a `video` parameter that can be null, and I'm trying to destructure it with defaults. Am coming across a couple of things that are confusing me (even having tried to read about it)

```
const VideoDetail = ({
    video = {},
} = {}) => {
    console.log(video);
    return 5; 
};
```

Surely `console.log(video)` here can't be null and should default to an empty object? It doesn't seem to be. Which is causing me problems in my actual question: Getting `TypeError: null has no properties`

```
const VideoDetail = ({
    video = {}, 
    video: { id: { videoId = 0 } = {} } = {}
} = {}) => {
    console.log(videoId);
    return 5;
};
```

I think it's because video is null. If it was actually an empty default object this wouldn't be happening, right?

What have I missed?

Thanks

Comment: Only `undefined` arguments are defaulted. If you need to deal with `null` inputs, you must do explicit checking in the function body.

Comment: Oh really? Well that explains that then! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default parameters are only used if the property is `undefined` (either not existent or explicitly set). Other falsy (`null`, `false` etc.) values are not replaced.

Read more here: [Default parameters - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)